# Cannot connect to Excel Connection Manager--Weirdest SSIS behavior I have ever seen

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ssis, network-drive

I have been running an SSIS solution for months now (have not edited it).  Here are the deets:

- Uses an `Excel Connection Manager`
- connects to an Excel workbook on a network drive that I have mapped to my PC.
- I run this package in debug.
- I usually run SSIS as admin

Now, before you say it's an SSIS to shared drive issue, here is the weird part...I can connect to other Excel workbooks on this shared drive.  It's this one particular folder where I cannot connect to Excel workbooks, even workbooks I have connected to in the past.  I can navigate to the shared drive and open these workbooks from my File Explorer.  And if I copy the files to my PC, I can connect.  If I copy the workbooks to another folder on the network drive, I can connect.  I tried not running as admin, and it still fails.

What is happening?

Comment: permissions of that folder are probably not correct.  If you can copy it to other locations including the network drive (presumably with different permissions) and it succeeds then the variable is permissions

Comment: Are you using the network FQDN or a drive letter?

Comment: @Matt The permissions for the folder are for Everyone...how do I check who SSIS is trying to run as?

Comment: @Eric Hauenstein I am using the full path...for example \\usaXXXX\folder\folder\file.xlsx